# Give outerspacepadding at x axis with time scale in d3 js

Tags: d3.js

I am beginner in d3 js so there is problem to shift x axis tick with time scale because in timescale axis there is no rangebound like ordinal axis which allow to give outerspacepadding like this .rangeBound[(0,width),0.5]
so is there any way to shift April in place of may as i mention in my given picture

[image: Need to shift april in place of may]
Here is the brief code for this above line graph..

```
    x = d3.time.scale()
      .domain(d3.extent(curr_data, function(d) { return formatDate.parse(d.year) ; }))
      .range([0, width]);

 y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(curr_data, function(d) { return d.value; })])      
        .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
        .tickSize(4,2,0)
      .orient("bottom");

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .innerTickSize(-width)
       .outerTickSize(0)    
    .tickPadding(5);

        chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis x-axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
       .selectAll("text")   
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

 chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis y-axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are using `d3.extent` to set the lower and upper domain limits of the time scale, and the result you're getting is the expected one. For instance, if we set the first date as April 2016 and the last date as April 2017, this is the axis we'll have:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var dates = [new Date(2016, 3, 1), new Date(2017, 3, 1)]

var scale = d3.time.scale()
 .domain(dates)
  .range([30,470]);
  
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(scale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(function(d){
  return d3.time.format("%b")(d)
  });
  
svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```css
line, path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

So, if you want to move `April` to the place of `May`, without messing with the axis itself, the best idea is simply subtracting 1 month from the lower domain limit (adding `Mar` at the start of that axis):

```
.domain([d3.time.month.offset(d3.min(dates), -1), d3.max(dates)])
```

Here, `dates` is my data array. Just replace it for `curr_data` or whatever data array you have.

Here is the result:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var dates = [new Date(2016, 3, 1), new Date(2017, 3, 1)]

var scale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([d3.time.month.offset(d3.min(dates), -1), d3.max(dates)])
  .range([30, 470]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format("%b")(d)
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```css
line,
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Also, if you don't want to see `Mar`, you can remove the first tick:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var dates = [new Date(2016, 3, 1), new Date(2017, 3, 1)]

var scale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([d3.time.month.offset(d3.min(dates), -1), d3.max(dates)])
  .range([30, 470]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(scale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
    if(i){
    return d3.time.format("%b")(d)
    } 
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```css
line,
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i need to start my April tick from May by leaving almost 1 tick gap as i have shown in my above picture..

Comment: And that's exactly what my answer does. I'll edit it for your exact months.

Comment: is there any way to hide the first tick as i have to show from April without showing march

Comment: @kunal Look at the answer again, last snippet.